# Polly Circuit breaker pattern - For testing connection strings

Tags: c#, circuit-breaker, polly

I'm trying to test whether the connection string is null using Polly.  If it is null, I want to try three times using the CircuitBreaker and the message should be outputted in the Console window.

```
Policy policy = null;
   
// Break the circuit after the specified number of exceptions
// and keep circuit broken for the specified duration.
policy = Policy
               .Handle<NullReferenceException>()
               .CircuitBreaker(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
try
{
    string connected = policy.Execute(() => repository.GetConnectionString());
}       
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",ex.Message);               
}
```

and the `GetConnectionString` method is:

```
public string GetConnectionString()
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test1"].ConnectionString;
     return conn.ConnectionString;
}
```

In order to test this, in the App.config I have changed the connection string name.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Testconnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=(Local);Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

However it doesn't seem to handle `NullReferenceException`.

When I debug the application - It opens CircuitBreakerEngine.cs not found and prints only

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Expected :
To print Object reference not set to an instance of an object thrice and teh message from the `BrokenCircuitException`

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have misunderstood what the `CircuitBreaker` policy does, as described at this similar question: [Polly framework CircuitBreakerAsync does not retry if exception occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398713/polly-framework-circuitbreakerasync-does-not-retry-if-exception-occur)

A circuit-breaker does not of itself orchestrate any retries.  Rather, it exists to *measure* the rate of faults on delegates executed through it - and trip the circuit if the fault rate becomes too high.  As its purpose is only as a *measuring*-and-breaking device, it indeed rethrows exceptions from delegates executed through it: hence the `NullReferenceException` you are seeing rethrown.

**EDIT**: This behaviour of the circuit-breaker, and its difference from retry, is also clearly described in the Polly wiki, at: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker

To do what I think you want to do, you need to combine retry policy with circuit breaker policy as described at [Polly framework CircuitBreakerAsync does not retry if exception occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398713/polly-framework-circuitbreakerasync-does-not-retry-if-exception-occur).  Polly now offers [PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) to make combining policies easy.