# No service for type 'Polly.Registry.IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry`1[System.String]' has been registered

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, policy-registry

There is an extension method that registers `IAccountSearchServiceClient` with some policy handlers looks like [Polly](https://discoverdot.net/projects/polly) lib is used

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddAccountSearchServiceClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<AccountSearchServiceClient>()
            .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, client) =>
             {
                 var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AccountSearchSettings>>();
                 var settings = options.Value;
                 client.BaseAddress = settings.BaseUrl;
             })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
             {
                 var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                 {
                     ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, cc, pe) => true
                 };
                 return handler;
             })
            .AddPolicyHandler(request => request.Method == HttpMethod.Get ? Policies.ShortTimeout : Policies.LongTimeout)
            .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry("circuitBreaker")
            .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry("bulkhead")
            .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry("RetryPolicy");

    services.AddScoped<IAccountSearchServiceClient>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AccountSearchServiceClient>());

    return services;
}
```

at runtime getting such a DI error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=No
> service for type
> 'Polly.Registry.IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry`1[System.String]' has been
> registered.
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

the error occurs here

```cs
sp.GetRequiredService<AccountSearchServiceClient>()
```

I'm not very familiar with Polly. Is there something missing?
I've put a break point on a constructor but the ctor is not called error happens earlier after `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler`

the consturctor looks as the following:

```cs
public AccountSearchServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<AccountSearchSettings> settings)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    _settings = settings?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
}
```

no direct injections or usages of `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry` I guess it's something internal type of Polly

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the missing part was the policy registration:

```cs
var policyRegistry = services.AddPolicyRegistry();

policyRegistry["circuitBreaker"] = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

policyRegistry["RetryPolicy"] = ...;

//etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Even though it seems quite appealing to have a registry with full of policies unfortunately it is error-prone. At the first glance it seems like it provides great flexibility by allowing the to combine whatever policies (s)he wants.

But there is a problem, which is related to the [escalation](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc). If the inner policy fails then Polly will escalate the problem to the next outer policy (in the policy chain) which may or may not be aware of the inner policy.

#### Example #1

Let's stick with your example where you have a Retry and a Circuit Breaker.
The consumer can combine them in the following two orders:

1. Circuit Breaker >> Retry
2. Retry >> Circuit Breaker

- In the former case the retry will not throw any Polly specific exception.
- But in the latter case Polly might throw `BrokenCircuitException`.

  - So depending on the use case your retry policy might need to be aware of that.

#### Example #2

Let's suppose you have a Timeout policy as well. This is where things can get quite complicated.
The Timeout can act either as a local or a global timeout:

1. Retry >> Circuit Breaker >> Timeout
2. Timeout >> Retry >> Circuit Breaker

+1. Timeout >> Retry >> Circuit Breaker >> Timeout

- In the first case your Timeout should not be aware of the any other Polly policies, but Circuit Breaker and Retry might need to be aware of the `TimeoutRejectedException`.
- In the second case your Timeout might need to be aware of `BrokenCircuitException`, ...
- In the bonus case how can you define a single policy which could be reused for local and global timeouts as well?

### Design

Fortunately Polly can help us with [Wrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap). You can explicitly combine two or more policies in a given order. This helps you define **strategies** not just individual policies.

So instead of exposing individual policies, you can expose strategies which combines a set of policies to achieve the desired behaviour.

Let's stick with the Retry >> Circuit Breaker >> Timeout example:

1. Timeout aware of: -
2. Circuit breaker aware of: `HttpRequestExcetion`, `TimeotRejectedException`
3. Retry aware of: `HttpRequestExcetion`, `TimeotRejectedException`, `BrokenCircuitException`

### Solution

Let's suppose we have the following abstraction to specify the parameters for the above three policies:

```cs
public class ResilienceSettings
{
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }

    public int HttpRequestTimeoutInMilliseconds { get; set; }

    public int HttpRequestRetrySleepDurationInMilliseconds { get; set; }

    public int HttpRequestRetryCount { get; set; }

    public int HttpRequestCircuitBreakerFailCountInCloseState { get; set; }

    public int HttpRequestCircuitBreakerDelayInMillisecondsBetweenOpenAndHalfOpenStates { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's see the policies:

```cs
private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> TimeoutPolicy(ResilienceSettings settings)
    => Policy
        .TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>( //Catches TaskCanceledException and throws instead TimeoutRejectedException
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(settings.HttpRequestTimeoutInMilliseconds));

private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CircuitBreakerPolicy(ResilienceSettings settings)
    => HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError() //Catches HttpRequestException or checks the status code: 5xx or 408
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() //Catches TimeoutRejectedException, which can be thrown by an inner TimeoutPolicy
        .CircuitBreakerAsync( //Monitors consecutive failures
            handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: settings
                .HttpRequestCircuitBreakerFailCountInCloseState, //After this amount of consecutive failures it will break
            durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(settings
                .HttpRequestCircuitBreakerDelayInMillisecondsBetweenOpenAndHalfOpenStates)); //After this amount of delay it will give it a try

private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> RetryPolicy(ResilienceSettings settings)
    => HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError() //Catches HttpRequestException or checks the status code: 5xx or 408
        .Or<BrokenCircuitException>() //Catches BrokenCircuitException, so whenever the broker is open then it refuses new requests
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>() //Catches TimeoutRejectedException, which can be thrown by an inner TimeoutPolicy
        .WaitAndRetryAsync( //Monitors the above anomalies
            retryCount: settings.HttpRequestRetryCount, //After (this amount + 1) attempts it gives up
            sleepDurationProvider: _ =>
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(settings.HttpRequestRetrySleepDurationInMilliseconds)); //After a failed attempt it delays the next try with this amount of time
```

And finally the extension method for registration:

```cs
public static class ResilientHttpClientRegister
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddXYZResilientStrategyToHttpClientProxy<TInterface, TImplementation>
        (this IServiceCollection services, ResilienceSettings settings)
        where TInterface: class
        where TImplementation: class, TInterface
    {
        var (serviceUri, combinedPolicy) = CreateParametersForXYZStrategy<TInterface>(settings);

        services.AddHttpClient<TInterface, TImplementation>(
                client => { client.BaseAddress = serviceUri; })
            .AddPolicyHandler(combinedPolicy); //Retry > Circuit Breaker > Timeout (outer > inner)

        return services;
    }

    private static (Uri, IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>) CreateParametersForXYZStrategy<TInterface>(ResilienceSettings settings)
    {
        Uri serviceUri = Uri.TryCreate(settings.BaseAddress, UriKind.Absolute, out serviceUri)
            ? serviceUri
            : throw new UriFormatException(
                $"Invalid url was set for the '{typeof(TInterface).Name}' resilient http client. " +
                $"Its value was '{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(settings.BaseAddress)}'");

        var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(RetryPolicy(settings), CircuitBreakerPolicy(settings), TimeoutPolicy(settings));

        return (serviceUri, combinedPolicy);
    }
}
```