# Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry to "funnel" all requests when hitting rate limit

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, polly, retry-logic

We're using the Dropbox API wrapped in Polly to handle retries.
We have it set up as an exponential back-off, like explained [here](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#wait-and-retry-with-exponential-back-off).

The issue we have is that we make plenty of concurrent calls.
When the API starts throwing rate limit exceptions, each individual caller backs off
but new callers will still call the API and "steal" the retry of callers that are waiting.
That means that on high load we are experiencing failed API calls and errors.

What we would like to achieve is that on rate limit errors all calls (including new callers) to the API are synchronized and wait for the rate limit to expire.
Then calls can resume (ideally in sequence to make sure the calls don't return rate limit exceptions anymore).

Is there a Polly-supported way of achieving that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements 100% (*the API are synchronized and wait for the rate limit to expire*). So, what do you want to do with those incoming requests while the downstream system is unavailable due to throttling?

Comment: Polly already does single-thread rate limit. I want the same functionality but across threads. We don't have that many callers so it's OK if the calls are held up.

Comment: So basically do you want to have a retry logic which is aware of a shared circuit breaker? If the rate limit exceeded then would the downstream system provide some kind of RetryAfter relative/absolute timespan?

Comment: Yes, the provider provides a RetryAfter timespan. And rather than a circuit breaker (=fail incoming calls) I just want to schdule them after the RetryAfter period.

Comment: Polly's Circuit Breaker offers a manual switch on/off capability by calling Isolate and Reset. With that we could implement a gating mechanism until the RetryAfter expires. If you wish I can  put together a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding you want to have the following:

1. The downstream system can throttle incoming requests
   1.1 The system is smart enough to provide a `RetryAfter` time span
2. You want to avoid flooding the downstream system if you already know that you are throttled
3. But you don't want to lose any incoming request rather prefer processing all of them eventually

---

Let's put together a working example

#### #1 - Downstream system

Here we will implement a super simple mock which can mimic throttling.

Let's start with the exception

```cs
public class DownstreamServiceException: Exception
{
    public TimeSpan RetryAfter { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's see the service code

```
public class DownstreamService
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource initCompletionSignal;
    private readonly TimeSpan initDuration;
    private bool isAvailable = false;
    private DateTime initEstimatedEnd;

    public DownstreamService()
    {
        initDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        initCompletionSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(initDuration);
        initCompletionSignal.Token.Register(() => isAvailable = true);
        initEstimatedEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(initDuration);
    }

    public Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        if (!isAvailable) throw new DownstreamServiceException { RetryAfter = initEstimatedEnd - DateTime.UtcNow };
        return Task.FromResult("Available");
    }
}
```

- For the sake of simplicity I've used made the service unavailable for the first 10 seconds
- I've used a `CancellationTokenSource` as a timer to make the service available
- If the `GetAsync` is called while it is not available (*we are throttled*) it returns an exception otherwise with the `"Available"` string

#### #2 - Avoid flooding is downstream is not available

Here we will define a Circuit Breaker to short-cut the requests if the downstream is not available (*we are throttled*)

```
var throttledPolicy = Policy<string>
    .Handle<DownstreamServiceException>()
    .CircuitBreakerAsync(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        onBreak: (result, state, _, __) => {
            if (state == CircuitState.Open) return;
            Console.WriteLine("onBreak");
            throw result.Exception;
        },
        onReset: (_) => Console.WriteLine("onReset"),
        onHalfOpen: () => { });
```

- The Circuit Breaker will transit from *Closed* to *Open* when we receive the first `DownstreamServiceException`
- The duration of break (`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)`) does not matter here

  - We will control the Circuit Breaker's state from the Retry logic
- `if (state == CircuitState.Open)`: This will be explained under the retry section
- And finally re-throw the original exception (I know, I know ... it should be avoided, but it keeps our example application simple)

#### #3 - Retry until eventually processed

This is the most complicated part of the solution, because this retry policy handles multiple exceptions (`DownstreamServiceException`, `IsolatedCircuitException`) in a different way

```
CancellationTokenSource throttlingEndSignal;
var retryPolicy = Policy<string>
    .Handle<DownstreamServiceException>()
    .Or<IsolatedCircuitException>()
    .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
        onRetry: (dr, __) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"onRetry caused by {dr.Exception.GetType().Name}");
            if (dr.Exception is DownstreamServiceException dse)
            {
                throttledPolicy.Isolate();
                throttlingEndSignal = new(dse.RetryAfter);
                throttlingEndSignal.Token.Register(() => throttledPolicy.Reset());
            }
        });
```

- Let's start with the `DownstreamServiceException`

  - We will receive this exception because we are going to chain together the two policies and Circuit Breaker's `onBreak` delegate re-throws the received exception
  - Inside the `onRetry` we have a guard expression for `DownstreamServiceException`
  - Here we call the `Isolate` on the Circuit Breaker, which tries to transit from *Open* state to *Isolated* state >> calls the `onBreak` delegate
  - In order to avoid infinite loop that's why we had this `if (state == CircuitState.Open) return;` code there
  - We do the same timer trick here with the `CancellationTokenSource`, when ever the throttling ends we push the Circuit Breaker back to *Closed* state (`Reset`)
- The `IsolatedCircuitException` case is much more simple

  - We receive this exception whenever we tries to perform a retry attempt but the Circuit Breaker is in *Isolated* state
  - So, the CB short cuts the execution and because of WaitAndRetry**Forever** call we will eventually succeed

#### Put things together

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, throttledPolicy);

var result = await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await service.GetAsync());
```

Please note the followings:

- This solution works well with multiple requests as well because Circuit Breaker is shared
- This solution is a workaround, because we ca not set the duration of break dynamically

I hope you found this little sample application useful :)

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. I was stumped understanding how the "retry" policy would fit with the "wait when throttled" requirement. Composing the policies is a very neat way of doing that.

Comment: @R4cOOn I'm glad to read that I could help :)