# Programatically re-executing/re-initiating the same request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

I have `ASP.NET 4.0` application.

In my application, if some exception (which may not occur if i perform the same operation after some delay) occurs during user workflow, we don't want user to do the same thing again. Instead, we would like to try to re-execute the same request programatically first.

I want to understand if this is possible? If yes, how can I do it? Any readymade solution (library, technology etc) available? And what all (high level) things I have to take care of if i have to write code myself in case there is no readymade solution?

Comment: While handling exception, you can simply give the response.Redirect to the same URL for which request was originated

Comment: Have you tried ciruit breaker pattern? look this answer using polly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176484/polly-circuit-breaker-pattern-for-testing-connection-strings

Comment: What is it that throws Exceptions? Maybe you should fix the code instead?

Comment: @mortb: We are thinking about this option only because of various complexities involved in the application & its layers.

Comment: If possible, try to isolate the unreliable part into its own part of the code (might be in a windows service or so) and implement it with retry functionality.